# Only use array keys that are strings

Tags: php, arrays, key

Say, for example, I have the following array:

```
Array
  (
    [test] => 3
    [0] => 2
    [test2] => 4
    [1] => 2
    [test3] => 5
    [2] => 2
  )
```

I am looking for a way to only select the array elements that have strings as keys, in this case, `test`, `test2`, and `test3`.

So, if I printed out the resulting array, it would output: `3, 4, 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the classic `foreach` to loop thru your array. You can check if the key is numeric by `is_numeric`

```
$arr = array(
    "test" => 3,
    "0" => 2,
    "test2" => 4,
    "1" => 2,
    "test3" => 5,
    "2" => 2
);

foreach( $arr as $key => $val ) {
    if ( !is_numeric( $key ) ) $result[] = $val;
}

echo implode(", ",$result);
```

This will result to:

> 3, 4, 5

Comment: Happy to help @John